# Can't run my code if my input is a file from another directory

Tags: python, operating-system

I'm new to python and I have a code that take as input a list of files. My code runs perfectly when those file are in my working directory, but when they are in another one, it tells me "there's no such file". Even after getting the list of files with "os.listdir" it still tells me the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
import os
os.chdir(path)
```

where path is the path of the directory where are stored the input files.
By default, when you run you python code, it will search in the same directory.
If you want that it look at in another, you have to specified it

Comment: Thx a lot my friend it works really thank you you dont know hwo long i've been stuck